# Silverman exercise 3.1 proving that two polynomials are relatively prime iff the discriminant is non-zero

Tags: elliptic-curves, computer-algebra-systems

Silverman, p. 104:

> Show that the polynomials
>   $$f=x^4−b_4x^2−2b_6x−b8 \qquad \text{and}\qquad g=4x^3+b_2x^2+2b_4x+b_6$$
>   appearing in the duplication formula (III.2.3d) are relatively prime if and only if the discriminant of the associated Weierstrass equation is nonzero.

I tried to do this in the most straightforward way with computer algebra, and I am surprised that it didn't work. Probably, there is a nice way to do it by hands, but I don't understand how my method gave me the wrong answer. I used SAGE to compute the resultant of $f$ and $g$ with respect to $x$, and I got:

SAGE: resultant$(f,g,x)=$
$-3*b_2^2*b_4^2*b_6^2 + 4*b_2^3*b_6^3 + 4*b_2^2*b_4^3*b_8 - 6*b_2^3*b_4*b_6*b_8 + b_2^4*b_8^2 + 108*b_4^3*b_6^2 - 162*b_2*b_4*b_6^3 - 144*b_4^4*b_8 + 240*b_2*b_4^2*b_6*b_8 + 6*b_2^2*b_6^2*b_8 - 48*b_2^2*b_4*b_8^2 + 729*b_6^4 - 1296*b_4*b_6^2*b_8 + 384*b_4^2*b_8^2 + 192*b_2*b_6*b_8^2 - 256*b_8^3$

My hope was that the discriminant, which is given by the formula below would be a factor of resultant$(f,g,x)$, but apparently not. I used the gcd and the factor function, and I got:

SAGE: gcd(resultant$(f,g,x)$, $D$)

$1$

SAGE: factor(resultant$(f,g,x)$)

resultant$(f,g,x)$

Comment: Where did you get the discriminant $D$?

Answer (score 2):

This is a hint, albeit a big hint, rather than the whole answer.

Subtract the square of the discriminant from the resultant and try factoring the difference.
This factorization should be all you need.

But, as you also write, it would be interesting to see a proof that does not depend on such symbolic manipulation, as I had to use computer algebra software for this too.

Answer (score 2):

I think you needed to use that $$b_8=\frac{b_2b_6-b_4^2}{4}$$.

In that case, I get that the gcd of the resultant the discriminant is exactly equal to the discriminant (see image below for the Sage output).

[image]

where I got the discriminant as 
$1/16*b_2^4*b_4^4 + (-1/8)*b_2^5*b_4^2*b_6 + 1/16*b_2^6*b_6^2 + (-4)*b_2^2*b_4^5 + 17/2*b_2^3*b_4^3*b_6 + (-9/2)*b_2^4*b_4*b_6^2 + 64*b_4^6 + (-144)*b_2*b_4^4*b_6 + 135/2*b_2^2*b_4^2*b_6^2 + 27/2*b_2^3*b_6^3 + 432*b_4^3*b_6^2 + (-486)*b_2*b_4*b_6^3 + 729*b_6^4$