# Silverman exercise 3.1

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, discriminant

I try to do exercise 3.1 from graduate elliptic curve by Silverman. I find a discussion here

[Silverman exercise 3.1 proving that two polynomials are relatively prime iff the discriminant is non-zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697068/silverman-exercise-3-1-proving-that-two-polynomials-are-relatively-prime-iff-the)

But I cannot make sense of what discussed there. Is this supposed to be a proof oriented exercise ? But it seems the calculation is so complicated to do by hand. Also, there is an attempt to use resultant (?) which I guess somehow relates to discriminant.

In short, I am confused and not sure where to begin. What should be the associated Weierstrass form ? I mean there are two polynomails, does the associated form refers to $$E : y^2 = 4x^3 + b_2x^2 + 2b_4x + b_6 ?$$

Comment: Two polynomials are relatively prime iff their resultant is nonzero. So it suffices to prove that the resultant is zero iff $\Delta$ is zero. You will also have to use the fact that $b_8=\frac{b_2b_6-b_4^2}{4}$ (Silverman p.42)

Comment: Is there any particular reason why go through resultant ? I mean why we just calculate the discriminant ? I saw in the other post that resultant is already hard to compute by hand. If I did not misunderstand, Silverman text has a formula for discriminant for elliptic curve $E$ of the form I wrote which seems a lot shorter and easier to compute. I just quite dont get what is going on in this problem.

Comment: If you forget the elliptic curves for a second, ask yourself the question how to check whether two polynomials f and g are relatively prime? Is there any general algorithm? One way is to factorize the polynomials into irreducible factors, but good luck with that... An easy way (easy for a computer at least) is to use what we call the resultant and check whether the resultant is zero or not.

Comment: As for the discriminant, it is the discriminant of the elliptic curve with Weirstrass eqn such that the duplication formula gives rise to the two polynomials in the exercise. A priori the discriminant doesn't appear (at least to me) to have much to do with the polynomials involved in the duplication formula; the exercise on the other hand is telling you that it does.